# Python - test whether object is a builtin function

Tags: python

Is there a nice way to check whether object o is a builtin Python function?

I know I can use, for example

```
type(o) == type(pow)
```

because type(pow) is 'builtin_function_or_method'.

But is there some nicer way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The types module:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.BuiltinFunctionType
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Though, if you look under the hood, you'll find it's not that different from what you're doing now.

So, in your case, use

```
isinstance(o, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
```

Comment: As @iMom0 said in his answer - you can use `isinstance(x, y)` instead of using `type(x) == type(z)`, I think it's more pythonic :)

Comment: This doesn't tell you if a function is builtin, it tells you if it is a natively-compiled C function.  Third-party modules with C extensions will also report their functions as this type.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I'm not sure the poster is interested in that distinction, but I guess we'll leave it up to him to comment.

Comment: @ThomasVanderStichele: yes, unfortunately, the OP doesn't provide much context, or tell us what aspect of "builtin" he's interested in.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the object is a builtin 'type' type, such as int. The following both return False: `isinstance(int, (types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.BuiltinMethodType))` and `isinstance(int.__init__, (types.BuiltinFunctionType, types.BuiltinMethodType))`. Is there a way to handle such cases?

Comment: @ScottH: Builtin types (e.g., `int`) are classes rather than callables. So, of *course* an `int` is neither a builtin function or method; it's a type. In other words, this does indeed work exactly as advertised. What you want is to [decide whether a given class is implemented in pure-Python or as a C extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16752719/2809027), a completely orthogonal question.

Comment: @CecilCurry, is there a way to check if a type is part of the built-in standard library? (Regardless whether implemented in C or pure Python)

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you mean by “built-in”.

**Using `__builtins__`**

If you want to check that your function is one of the built-in functions in the Python interpreter you can use

```
>>> pow in __builtins__.__dict__.values()
True
>>> __builtins__.__dict__['pow']
<built-in function pow>
```

The Python interpreter has a number of built-in constants, functions, types, and exceptions, that are contained in the dictionary `__builtins__.__dict__`.

**Using `BuiltinFunctionType`**

If on the other hand you want to check if your function is of type `BuiltinFunctionType` you can use the `types` module

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(pow, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
```

**Using `inspect`**

Or `inspect.isbuiltin` (just a wrapper around `isinstance(object, types.BuiltinFunctionType)`)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isbuiltin(pow)
True
```

**Note that the term “built-in” in `BuiltinFunctionType` means “written in C”.**

Consider the following example:

```
>>> from math import factorial
>>> isinstance(factorial, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
```

The `factorial` function is of type `BuiltinFunctionType` but it's not a builtin function in the interpreter

```
>>> factorial in __builtins__.__dict__.values()
False
```

This is because the `math` module in Python consists of wrappers around the C math library functions.

Being able to detect a `BuiltinFunctionType` is useful because for functions written in Python one can inspect the source code without having to open the source files.

```
>>> import random
>>> isinstance(random.random, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
>>> inspect.getsource(random.random)
# returns TypeError
>>> isinstance(random.uniform, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False
>>> from __future__ import print_function # if using Python 2.*
>>> print(inspect.getsource(random.uniform))
    def uniform(self, a, b):
        "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
        return a + (b-a) * self.random()
```

Comment: Worth noting that this also means "map" is classified wrongly in Python 3, as it is technically a class and not a function anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(pow, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
True
>>> def a():
    pass
>>> isinstance(a, types.BuiltinFunctionType)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
import __builtin__
o in __builtin__.__dict__.values()
```

or, in CPython:

```
o in __builtins__.__dict__.values()
```

but note that you rely on an implementation detail here.

---

```
>>> pow in __builtins__.__dict__.values()
True
>>> def a():
...   pass
...
>>> a in __builtins__.__dict__.values()
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although some time has passed, perhaps other people will find my answer useful since this question has popped up in my search for an answer.

In case you are only interested in testing rather a given variable `var` is one of the following:

1. `function`
2. `builtin_function_or_method` but not a `method`

I found the following test to work:

```
import types

def is_func(arg):
    return isinstance(arg, types.FunctionType) or \
        (isinstance(arg, types.BuiltinFunctionType) and
            arg.__self__ is None)
```

Hope i am correct in my assumption, but the general idea is that if we have been given a `builtin_method` it must have a type not `None` associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if builtins has it as an attribute and it's callable. Samples:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'max')
True
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'abs')
True
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'aaa')
False
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'True')
True
>>> callable(abs)
True
>>> callable(True)
False
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'max') and callable(max)
True
>>> hasattr(builtins, 'True') and callable(True)
False
```