# Determine whether a Python function is already implemented in C extension

Tags: python, cython

Suppose I have a Python program that runs slow- after profiliing and I have identified the bottleneck. One particular function from a 3rd party module I imported is particularly slow.

For this particular case, I know that function is implemented in Python (Used Eclipse and it's easy to jump to the function definition). So I know that I can convert that function into Cython as a speed-up option. (If it is already implemented in C, there is no point in writing it in Cython...).

If I don't have an IDE, what would be an easy option to determine this?
I know that I can go to the directory where the module is installed and infer that it is in C if the module is in .so. But is there any alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether it is an instance of [`types.FunctionType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.FunctionType):

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(len, types.FunctionType)
False
>>> def mylen(): pass
... 
>>> isinstance(mylen, types.FunctionType)
True
```

Probably you'd be safer to check for `isinstance(X, (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType)`.

C functions are instances of `builtin_function_or_method`:

```
>>> len.__class__
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> np.vdot.__class__
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

You can access this type as `types.BuiltinFunctionType`/`types.BuiltinMethodType`.

Alternatively you can check whether the function has a `__code__` attribute. Since C functions do not have bytecode, they can't have `__code__`.

Note sometimes what seems like a function is actually a `class`, e.g. `enumerate` but some 3rd party library may do the same. This means that you should also check whether a class is implemented in C or not. This one is harder since all classes are instances of `type`. A way may be to check whether the class has a `__dict__` in its `dir`, and if it doesn't have you should check for `__slots__`.

Something like the following should be pretty accurate:

```
def is_implemented_in_c(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, (types.FunctionType, types.LambdaType)):
        return False
    elif isinstance(obj, type):
        if '__dict__' in dir(obj): return False
        return not hasattr(obj, '__slots__')
    # We accept also instances of classes.
    # Return True for instances of C classes, False for python classes.
    return not isinstance(obj, types.InstanceType)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> is_implemented_in_c(enumerate)
True
>>> is_implemented_in_c(len)
True
>>> is_implemented_in_c(np.vdot)
True
>>> is_implemented_in_c(lambda x: True)
False
>>> is_implemented_in_c(object)
True
>>> class A(object):
...     __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
... 
>>> is_implemented_in_c(A)
False
```

Comment: Thans for a very good answer - However, one minor problem. If the C function "cf" is wrapped by another Python "pf" , and you call is_implemented_in_c(pf), it will return False. Sadly we can't say "Oh, this is a Python function, and I can convert to Cython to speed up!" If the C function is wrapped by a single line Python function, certainly we can recursively determine this is a C function in disguise of Python. However, if pf is is a multiline function and cf is called somewhere inside pf, it becomes difficult to determine whether pf is just a wrapper for cf or not.

Comment: @user2005856 I was well aware of this, but there isn't a solution for that case, and *it has been proven*. What you want to do is to decide a semantic property from the text of a function. By Rice theorem either the property is trivial(e.g. always True or False) or it is undecidable. You can try to write some complex stuff that will work on *some* functions, but this will **never** work in the general case, no matter how hard you try. If you find a python wrapper, read the source code/the disassembly using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module and find the real c func.

Comment: **Caveat:** the `is_implemented_in_c()` function assumes the existence of the Python 2.x-specific `types.InstanceType` attribute detecting old-style classes, which (*...for hopefully obvious reasons*) no longer exists under Python 3.x. That function isn't quite doing what it's advertised as doing. In fact, it's horrifyingly wrong. Under CPython, C-based objects are trivially detected by the following snippet: `is_obj_c = bool(type(obj).__flags__ & (1<<9))`, where `(1<<9)` is the magic number `_Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` in the `Include/object.h` C header within the official CPython codebase.