# inspect.getsource() doesn't work in python

Tags: python

I have a problem with this code , but don't no why...

```
import inspect
inspect.getsource(min)
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    inspect.getsource(min)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\inspect.py", line 726, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\inspect.py", line 715, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\inspect.py", line 551, in findsource
    file = getfile(object)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\inspect.py", line 435, in getfile
    'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
TypeError: <built-in function min> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame,or code object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in `min()` is implemented in C code, and `inspect.getsource()` can only show you *Python* code:

```
>>> min
<built-in function min>
```

The `built-in function` type is always implemented in C.

The code for this function comes from the `bltinmodule.c` source file; the [`builtin_min()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd95f1276360/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1448) delegates to the [`min_max()` utility function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd95f1276360/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1345) in the same source file.

Comment: @PooyaFayyaz: the error message already tells you it is a built-in.

Comment: @Pooya, see [Python - test whether object is a builtin function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347647/python-test-whether-object-is-a-builtin-function).